# Как сделать рекомендательную систему?

Tags: c#

Как сделать рекомендательную систему в С#?

Comment: А что такое «рекомендательная система», для начала?

Comment: это подбор музыки/видео/чего угодно по вкусу пользователя.

Comment: Хм.

1. Придумать алгоритм (это сложная часть)
2. Реализовать его на C# (это простая часть)
3. Добавить базу данных с музыкой/видео/чем угодно.

Вы уже алгоритм придумали?

Comment: @VladD Насчет п. 2 и 3 могу поспорить. Объемы и скорость работы могут привести к очень сложным реализациям.

Не все алгоритмы основаны на информации о контенте. К примеру, коллаборативная фильтрация ничего не знает о контенте, кроме оценок пользователей. Возникает вопрос, как получить достаточный объем оценок.

Вероятностые алгоритмы также опираются не на свойства контента, а на поведение пользователя в сравнении с другими пользователями. 

Естественно, лучше работает комбинация разных алгоритмов, и тогда встает вопрос, как ранжировать выдачу от разных алгоритмов.
 
Развлечение на годы. :)

Comment: @a_gura: Мне кажется, реализовать хорошо специфицированный алгоритм — тривиальная задача, особенно на достаточно высокоуровневом языке. Разве нет?

Или вы имеете в виду, что алгоритм будет _настолько_ неэффективен/трудоёмок, что придётся заботиться о низкоуровневых оптимизациях?

Comment: @VladD Большие объемы данных (а без них целые классы алгоритмов не имеют смысла) и требования к скорости работы могут создать достаточно хлопот и без низкоуровневых оптимизаций. 

Кроме того, автор вопроса говорит о рекомендательной системе, а не об алгоритме. Это очень разные вещи.

Comment: VladD. Алгоритмы есть. По крайней мере их начало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам нужно разобраться в типах рекомендательных алгоритмов. Выбрать набор подходящих. Кроме того, нужно оценивать качество ваших рекомендаций. В общем это дело не быстрое. Причем язык программирования здесь играет последнюю роль.

Могу порекомендовать книгу [Recommender Systems Handbook](http://www.amazon.com/Recommender-Systems-Handbook-Francesco-Ricci/dp/0387858199). Для начала пойдет.

Answer (score -1):

Как я понял:
Реализовать абстрактный класс класс с тэгами. Унаследовать от этого класса и создать классы песня, фильм, книга, игра. Создать экземпляры классов, пример: "Пила", тэги: "ужасы". Задавать пользователю вопросы, добавляя в список тэги. Сдеалать поиск по все элементам на соответствие тэгам.

Comment: То есть ваш алгоритм — соответствие тегов? Например, если человек посмотрел детектив про Эркюля Пуаро, то вы ему посоветуете «Молчание ягнят»?

Comment: Если в базе всего два фильма - то так и придется делать:)
Но в целом, подбные системы смотрят так. Пользователь А посмотрел фильмы Х1, Х2 и Х3, а пользователь Б посмотрел только Х1 и Х2. Значит, есть смысл порекомендовать пользователю Б посмотреть фильм Х3.

Да, на самом деле смотрят не на одного пользователя, а на группы, но суть не меняется.

Comment: @KoVadim: Ну, вы по существу описали другую систему тегов, где тег фильма есть пользователь, который его посмотрел. Плюс подбор соответствия по мощности пересечения.